# Convert VARCHAR date to datetime on MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, datetime

I currently have about 100 dates stored as `mm/dd/yyyy` that I need converted to default datetime format for a mysql server. `YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00`

I've simply tried to change the type to datetime, and no luck, as I would figure, not really sure where to start.

Comment: I updated the tags to match the question better. You can (and normally should) achieve this with pure mysql. Furthermore, phpmyadmin is just a tool, you're not coding *it*, so no tag is needed for that as no tag is needed for `computer` or `mouse`.

Comment: I take it you'd like to permanently change the type of the field?

Comment: Create a new datetime column, update the new column with `STR_TO_DATE()`, then drop the old column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you guys, I did not know about the STR_TO_DATE function

UPDATE `my_table` SET `column_name`=str_to_date(`column_name`, '%m/%d/%Y');

Worked just perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Use [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

```
select str_to_date(your_date_column, '%m/%d/%Y')
from your_table
```